# Springfox 2.8.0 unable to infer the base URL

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

After updating Springfox to 2.8.0, I started to experience the following issue:

[image]

Swagger tries to access the following resource:

http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html/swagger-resources/configuration/ui

instead of a correct one:

http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-resources/configuration/ui

How to fix it?

Comment: There's no "Swagger 2.8.0" because Swagger is [not a single project](https://swagger.io/tools/). Do you maybe mean Springfox?

Comment: Yes,sorry, I mean Springfox